# Could this be used for redis

Tags: redis

I have been advised to take a look at redis for a nodejs app I am building. I think it looks really neat! I have gone through the try redis application but am confused on one point, how do you model something like this in a key based architecture?

When someone vists my webpage, I would like to store: Date, Os, Browser, and Browser version to display as stats on the page.

I could store it all as completely separate keys, but that would make it impossible to do something like: How many people visited my site yesterday on windows running chrome 28.

How would you model something like this in redis? Should I use sql instead? Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Redis is the best tool to do what you want to do. Redis is great, but is not very much than a key/value storage server. Although you can search for patterns in keys and make indexes do fancy stuff (specially intervals of dates in your case) it would lead to a messy database both to make and to use.

I have used nodejs+redis before, and for pub/sub functionalities it`s nice. But in your case you will be better with sql. Or check mongoDB, it's really powerful and  easy to use with [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/).